# Install VTK for python 3

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, vtk

I am under OSX (Mojave) and using Python 3.7.0. In order to install a python package to visualise results (Mayavi) I need to install vtk with python 3 bindings.
I have installed python 3.7.0 with brew

I attempted the following:

- `python3 -m pip install vtk`. I get:

  ```
  Collecting vtk
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for vtk
  ```
- `brew install vtk --without-python@2`does not allow to install the python 3 wrappers
- `brew install vtk --with-python --without-python@2` gives:

  ```
  [10%] Built target vtkCommonMath
  make: *** [all] Error 2

  READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
  ```
- I also tried to follow [this tutorial](http://ghoshbishakh.github.io/blog/blogpost/2016/07/13/building-vtk-with-python3-wrappers.html) but I could not find  `VTK_WRAP_TCL` in the available options of the ccmake. I set the following options:

  - `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` :`/usr/local/bin/python3`
  - `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR`:          `/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m`

  Compiling VTK goes fine. But when I try to compile the wrappers, the `sudo make install` gives:

  ```
  [100%] Built target vtkpython
  Install the project...
  -- Install configuration: "Debug"
  -- Installing: /usr/lib/libvtkCommonCorePython37D-8.2.1.dylib
  CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
    file INSTALL cannot copy file "/Users/marco.magliulo/Software/vtkBuild/lib/libvtkCommonCorePython37D-8.2.1.dylib"
    to "/usr/lib/libvtkCommonCorePython37D-8.2.1.dylib".
  ```

Is there a simple way to get the python 3 wrappers that I did not try ?
Is there something obvious that I am missing in the different attempts I made?